# TSQL Batch insert - math doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, insert-select

I need to insert 1.3 million of records from one table into another, and it takes really long time (over 13 min). After some research I found that it is better to do this operation in batches, so I put together something like this (actual query is more complicated, it is simplified here for briefness):

```
DECLARE @key INT; SET @key = 0; 
CREATE TABLE #CURRENT_KEYS(KEY INT)

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
   -- Getting subset of keys
   INSERT INTO #CURRENT_KEYS(KEY)   
   SELECT TOP 100000 KEY FROM #ALL_KEYS WHERE KEY > @key
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK

   -- Main Insert
   INSERT INTO #RESULT(KEY, VALUE)
   SELECT MAIN_TABLE.KEY, MAIN_TABLE.VALUE 
   FROM MAIN_TABLE INNER_JOIN #CURRENT_KEYS 
   ON MAIN_TABLE.KEY = #CURRENT_KEYS.KEY

   SELECT @key = MAX(KEY ) FROM #CURRENT_KEYS

   TRUNCATE TABLE #CURRENT_KEYS
END
```

I already have indexed list of 1.3 million keys in #ALL_KEYS table so idea here is in a loop create smaller subset of keys for the JOIN and INSERT. The above loop executes 13 times (1,300,000 records / 100,000 records in a batch). If I put a break after just one iterations - execution time is 9 seconds. I assumed total execution time would be 9*13 seconds, but it's the same 13 minutes!

Any idea why?

NOTE: Instead of temp table #CURRENT_KEYS, I tried to use CTE, but with the same result.

**UPDATE** Some wait stats.

I am showing for this process `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` and sometimes `PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER` in wait stats occasionally over 500ms, but often < 100Ms. Also SP_WHO shows user as `suspended` for the duration of the query.

Comment: Did you measure any wait stats and see what is taking 13 minutes? Could be autogrow of log, tempdb data file, blocking, who knows?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not really sure how to do it, I am not a DBA and have little experience in optimization

Comment: You [may find this a useful read](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). Or someone you hire who does have experience in optimization. :-) Did you try using transactions inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks I will look into the article. I tried surround the inner insert by transaction as well as entire loop - had no effect.

Comment: Question: Do inserts into temp table getting logged as well?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did some wait stats research and updated the post. Is it useful? How can I act on this find? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're experiencing disk pressure.  PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER is an autogrowth event (database getting larger), and PAGEIOLATCH_SH means that the process is waiting for a latch on a buffer that's an IO request (probably your file growth event).

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/02/19/sql-server-preemptive-and-non-preemptive-wait-type-day-19-of-28/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/02/09/sql-server-pageiolatch_dt-pageiolatch_ex-pageiolatch_kp-pageiolatch_sh-pageiolatch_up-wait-type-day-9-of-28/

What I would recommend is pre-growing both tempdb (for your temp table) and the database that's going to hold the batch insert.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2091024

Comment: Results is inserted into temp table as well, do I still need to pre-grow main DB? Also what's the recommended size of temp db? Originally it was 200Mb I increased it to 500Mb, but see no noticable results.

Comment: If the main DB is experiencing autogrowth events, then yes.  

The recommended size of tempdb is "it depends," alas.  I benchmark mine under typical load and set it to a reasonable number for my server load at startup.  (Tempdb grows under load, but reverts to its original specified size at start up.)  

This article on optimizing tempdb might help.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I doubled in size both TempDB an main DB and this didn't affect the speed. Most of the times `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait is very small 20-50ms could it still have such a huge effect on delay or is it something else?

Comment: Are the files still growing?  Is it possible that the inserts are overlapping in a way that causes them to block each other?

Comment: As far as I can see, file sizes stay the same as the initial size